Multipart POST request not working in Karate but the same API call working fine in POSTMAN
I'm trying to upload a file through a multipart post request api in karate, however I have been getting a response 400 - an error stating file is in an incorrect format more specifically a file mime type error. But when i hit the same api in postman with the exact same file it is working fine without any errors. Anyone know what reason that would be causing this issue? The api input is a file in form-data.
I have checked the headers of both calls from postman and karate, no issues has been found - they are the same. However I have noticed that the multipart from karate sends charset=utf-8  in the request and i think that is what is causing the error as the backend is not expecting charset=utf-8.
Below is the multipart request body from karate
Mixed: content-disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file.txt"
content-type: multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 563
Completed: true
IsInMemory: true

Below is an example code that i have
Feature: File upload

  Background:
    Given url baseUrl
    # initiate authentication
  
  @form-data
  Scenario: Uploading file 
    * def filePath = 'classpath:file.txt'
    * configure headers = {'Authorization': '#(authorization)', Accept: 'application/json'}}
    Given path fileConversionApi
    And multipart file file = { read: '#(filepath)', filename: 'file.txt', contentType: 'multipart/form-data' }
    When method post
    Then status 200
    Then print response

I have tried adding * configure charset = null to the karate test but it still sends utf-8 in the multipart request. I also observed that the content-length is different from the request sent from postman and from the request sent in karate. For example the same request in postman has content-length as 773 while the request sent from karate has content length 750.
Has anyone experienced something similar where are multipart request works on postman but not karate?

I checked, and this snippet below shows that * configure charset = null works, and I think in older versions of Karate it was indeed an issue. I tried on 1.4.1
* configure charset = null
* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* multipart file myFile = { value: 'xxx' }
* method post

You can see the difference if you comment out the first line. So try upgrading.
For more tips on troubleshooting multipart, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78547136/143475
